Need to disable TPM but can't?
as the title says. I need to disable TPM. But, I don't see it in my BIOS. How can I do it? I've seen a topic back in 2022 where a guy asked the same question. But, my motherboard is different. It's the G713PVEC from Asus ROG I have a gaming laptop. Yep... Maybe that makes it hard, I tried everything. Literally everything. I want to flash my Bios but too scared for that. Maybe downgrade to Win10 and see if I have TPM option in BIOS? Or can I do it without going into BIOS? It needs to be fully disabled. Please seek me out of this.

If there is no option to disabled it, which is required by Microsoft, if the device came with Windows how do you know it’s enabled?

TPM can be a part of the processor (intel) or the motherboard (AMD). If it is from the processor, you cannot disable TPM.

I think we have a little bit of an A/B problem here.  Why do you need to disable TPM, perhaps we can solve the underlying issue?
